# Switching automatically between Anaconda environments

Tags: python, bash, anaconda

I am using Anaconda 4.3.11 and on Linux (Ubuntu Server) and need to find a way to switch automatically between Anaconda environments (because of incompatible package versions: I need `gdal 2.1.0` in the first part of my processing, and `gdal 2.1.3` in the second part).

So for the first processing steps I need `env1`, for the second part I need `env2`.

Manually typing `source activate env1` works fine. But I need to run my scripts as cronjobs, so this is not an option.

I have tried the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source activate sen2cor
conda info --envs
```

I understand that this won't work because of the `source` and some problems with trying to use it in a subshell (or something like that).

But there must be a way to switch environments automatically, isn't it?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean **`conda info --envs`** and not `conda list --envs`?

Comment: Correct, it is `conda info --envs`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work fine for activating a conda env in a cron job, you just need to add to your `PATH` in the same way you that you would in a regular session (or as is done in your ~/.bash* configuration files).

Basically, just like:

```
PATH=/home/roland/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
source activate sen2cor
```

Comment: Perfect, I used your approach in a shell script which is started as a cron job and which itself starts my python script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run scripts with different virtual environments, you don't have to switch to that environment. You can just use required python executable's absolute path.

E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
/Users/you/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/python script1.py
/Users/you/.virtualenvs/env2/bin/python script2.py
```